# using react-button gives warning of unknown props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

In package.json 's dependencies, I have:

```
"react": "15.6.1",
"react-dom": "15.6.1",
"react-button": "1.2.1"
```

and when I simply import the button by

```
import Button from 'react-button'
```

And then use it as:

```
<Button>Hello</Button>
```

This gives me the warning of:

```
Warning: Unknown props `isReactButton`, `applyDefaultTheme`, `buttonStates`, `align`, `defaultStyle`, `defaultDisabledStyle`, `defaultLabelStyle`, `ellipsisLabelStyle`, `ellipsis`, `themes`, `theme`, `active`, `over`, `focused` on <a> tag. Remove these props from the element.
```

Apparently, none of this props are provided by me, so I think it probably relates to dependencies' versions.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is a 3 year old outdated library, i'd suggest you use something else. Chances are the new version of React doesn't support the old implementation done in this library which is so old.

Comment: @AdeelImran you mean the react-button is too old? What else do you suggest to replace it? It still has 800 weekly downloads on npm but I am happy to switch to something stable!

Comment: Try react-strap (implementation of bootstrap in react) use react-material-ui, ant-design, all of these libraries have a complete list ui components. Button being one of them. But if you only need it for a button i'd suggest writing your own. It's fairly simple. Your choice.